# Ruby on Rails Debian best practice

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-practices, rubygems

I've seen in various places people using Ruby compiled from source through a cloned rbenv git repository, and then installing Rails through RubyGems to get the latest version.

But, from what I know, this is not a best practice in Debian, and they recommend [getting everything from apt-get](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian), as it may cause problems when updating Debian later.

So, I'm lost here, should I stick with the Rails package available on Debian APT? (I know it is Rails 4.1, I don't mind the shiny new stuff syndrome, but how can I assure that it is getting security fixes through Debian?)

I can't believe compiling Ruby from source through rbenv and installing passenger, unicorn and rails through RubyGems is stable enough to a production server, that is really how people configure production environments?